# Change value of same dropdown in other rows of radgrid when one dropdown value is changed

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a drop down with yes/no as data inside a rad grid. When the value of dropdown in row is changed, values of dropdown in other rows excluding this should be set with second item. This must be done with javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You could open [this link](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/postback-while-in-radgrid-edit-form-mode.aspx).

In addition, I would suggest you changing this line:

```
GridEditFormItem item = DropDownList1.NamingContainer as GridEditFormItem;
```

to

```
GridEditableItem item = DropDownList1.NamingContainer as GridEditableItem;
```

in order to support both edit and insert scenario.

Answer (score 0):

it would require 2 steps

1. right click on the dropdown a pop up will appear then check the postback option
2. after that simply double click on the dropdownlist as a result function will get created in your filename.cs file now put the code for adding the option for the other dropdown list there and u r done

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Pritam. I think you have misunderstood my requirements. I have a drop down inside a griditem, suppose if there are 4 rows i will have four drop downs. These drop down has Yes,No as their items. If one of the drop down in a row is changed from Yes to No, all the other drop down values must be changed to NO in client side, using java script or jquery.